# How can I reliably set net.core.ipv4.conf.rp_filter = 0 on CentOS 7?

Tags: networking, centos7, sysctl

I would like to disable reverse-path filtering on a CentOS 7 machine. I have a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/` that contains the following in an attempt to disable it for all of my network interfaces:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0f0.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0f1.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0f2.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0f3.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ens1f0.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.ens1f1.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
```

However, after boot, the `all` and `default` entries are still set to 1. I have to manually set them after booting the system to make them 0 as desired. Likewise, if I stop and restart networking via `systemctl restart network.service`, they are reset to 1 again.

Is there any way to make this setting stick the way I want it to?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I was burned by the fact that there is another directory, `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/`, whose contents are also considered (in lexicographical order) when applying sysctl options at boot time. There was an existing file, `50-default.conf`, lexicographically later than my file, that was setting:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
```

I renamed my file to come later than this one and it works.

Comment: This is not just *another* directory it's the way systemd prefers to handle sysctl, not shipping one monolithic file that gets you in trouble during package upgrades. *»/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf: a drop-in directory for kernel sysctl parameters, extending what you can already do with /etc/sysctl.conf.«* http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/the-new-configuration-files

Comment: My point was that I didn’t realize that there was one directory at /etc/sysctl.d/ and another at /usr/lib/sysctl.d and that both directories’ contents are merged before the lexicographical sort. So, you really need to check both places to ensure that there isn’t a file that comes later in the sort order that changes the setting you want to affect.

Comment: Mine is set like "net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2". What is it?

Comment: Not only 'both' places. `man sysctl` lists the following order:        /proc/sys
       /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /run/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /etc/sysctl.conf
(valid for at least Ubuntu 22.04 and Debian Bullseye)

Comment: @Smile https://sysctl-explorer.net/net/ipv4/rp_filter/ — or, if you prefer, from the [Linux kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt): Loose mode as defined in RFC3704 Loose Reverse Path |
     Each incoming packet's source address is also tested against the FIB
     and if the source address is not reachable via any interface
     the packet check will fail.